# How to target only youtube iframe urls?

Tags: jquery, youtube

I'm looking for a way to target this jquery only at src url's that have "youtube.com" in them. I've tried using the :contains selector but I can't get it working correctly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('iframe').each(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr("src")
        $(this).attr("src",url+"&amp;wmode=transparent")
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the attribute selector to target only iframes with a `src` containing `youtube.com`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').each(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr("src")
        $(this).attr("src",url+"&amp;wmode=transparent")
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Does the `&amp;` need to be escaped?

Comment: No. the valid HTML entity for the ampersand is read by the browser simply as `&`. There is no need to escape the entity.

Comment: I think that came out incorrectly: does the `&` need to be escaped in the `src` attribute? I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! And as for & being escaped, no it doesn't.